# Execute promises in an array sequentially socket.io

Tags: javascript, async-await, socket.io

I have a simple function `createRun()` which returns a Promise. The promise evaluates to an object. The code inside the function is not really relevant. I have another function called `createGroupRun()` which basically loops through an array(`testIds`) and calls the create run function. Now, when the `createRun()` function is done, I want to emit this:

```js
io.emit('group run created', {run, testId});
```

I have this `createGroupRun()`:

```js
export async function createGroupRun(projectId: string, testIds: string[], runIds: string[], reqUrl: string) {
    try {
        const groupRunId = uuid();

        const projectPath = path.resolve(__dirname, `../../projects/${projectId}`);

        await mkdir(`${projectPath}/group-${groupRunId}`);

        const runPromises = testIds.map(async (testId) => createRun(projectId, testId, reqUrl));

        return group;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        return error;
    }
}
```

`runPromises` contains the result of calling the `createRun()` function. I want to loop through this, execute the createRun function, emit the event shown above, move on to the next element, execute the `createRun` function, emit event... rinse and repeat.

How can this be done? There a lot of questions regarding this but none with socket.io

Comment: `execute the createRun function` too late, it's already been executed in each iteration of `.map` - regular for loop in an async function awaiting each iteration is how it should be done

Comment: OK then can you post an answer regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to run asynchronous code using async/await in a loop, in series rather than parallel - use a `for` loop

```
export async function createGroupRun(projectId: string, testIds: string[], runIds: string[], reqUrl: string) {
    try {
        const groupRunId = uuid();
        const projectPath = path.resolve(__dirname, `../../projects/${projectId}`);
        await mkdir(`${projectPath}/group-${groupRunId}`);
        for (let testId of testIds) {
            await createRun(projectId, testId, reqUrl);
        }
        return group;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}
```